# How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: jasper-reports, oracle-adf, glassfish-4

I have adf 1.2.2.1.4 application in glassfish 4.1 and my reports didn't work and show this error:

i'm using jasper report 5.6.0
i have this jar :
1- jasperreports-5.6.0
2- jasperreports-chart-themes-5.6.0
3- jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0
4- iText-2.1.7.js2
5- jcommon-1.0.15
6- jfreechart-1.0.12
7- poi-3.9
8- spring
9-common-digester-2.1-javadoc
10-common-digester-2.1
the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:81)
    at view.backing.Dev_report.runReport(Dev_report.java:148)
    at view.backing.Dev_report.Inter_sn(Dev_report.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1673)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:798)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:380)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:591)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:587)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextPropagator.processInScope(ExternalContextPropagator.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:596)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:591)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:587)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextPropagator.processInScope(ExternalContextPropagator.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:596)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:372)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$1.call(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:368)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextPropagator.processInScope(ExternalContextPropagator.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to download **commons-logging** jar to resolve this issue

Comment: I download commons-loggin1.1 the error is change to :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.I'm using  DejaVu Sans font in jasper .